# How to change a font in RMarkdown2 presentation?

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using RStudio RMarkdown2 **ioslides_presentation**. When I'm using non-english letters, like 'ę', it's looking really bad:

[image]

How to easily change a font in RMarkdown2 presentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Rmarkdown presentation

When using the `ioslides` rmarkdown presentation, I think the only way to change the font family is to provide a custom CSS. So you have to add the following in your preamble :

```
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: style.css
```

And then create a `style.css` file in your presentation directory with something like that :

```
* {font-family: Helvetica !important}
```

### RStudio R presentation

With RStudio R presentations, as explained here :

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532307-Customizing-Fonts-and-Appearance

You can specify a `font-family` setting in the preamble of your `rmarkdown` file. Something like this :

```
Presentation title
========================================
author: My name
font-family: 'Helvetica'
```

This will define the font family for the whole document. If you want to customize only some elements such as headers, you will have to create and add a custom CSS file.

Comment: @JoteN Edited. I don't know if the downvote is yours, but it seems a bit rude to me.

Comment: Yes, it was mine. Sorry, it wasn't my intention to be rude. I've only tried to inform others, that this answer is not correct. Thanks a lot for your help!